# rails change layout based on config

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm new with rails and I want to change the layout based on a config file (or something in the database).
I've forked a project and I want to change the logo and other images / texts based on a configuration. I want to make a dropdown menu which people can choose the project layout.
To be clear I have something like this :

```
<img src="link_to_logo1"/>
```

and I want a dropdown menu to choose between

```
<img src="link_to_logo1>
```

and

```
<img src="link_to_logo2>
```

That's not the only thing I want to change, I want to change the title too and other image. I'm wondering if there is something like a dropdown menu to choose a variable, and in a config file (like a json) I can put

```
{"choice 1" : {"logoimg" : "logo1.png", "title": "title choice 1"},
 "choice 2" : {"logoimg": "logo2.png", "title": "title choice 2"}}
```

And then in the layout I want something like

```
<img src="<%= srcLogoImg %>">
```

which srcLogoImg is based on the json config[:choice][:logoimg]

Comment: Do you want this to persist between requests? Or just go back to normal one the page is refreshed/navigated?

Comment: i want this to be persistent, maybe not a dropdown but just something in the config file. In fact i want the app to be deploy by people and peole who deploy it can change the layout. A dropdown would be nice because it's easier for the final user (they don't have to change a config file) but maybe it's harder to code. I don't know